# ~/.smartgit/<main-smartgit-version> What is the version to be given in <main-smartgit-version>? where is the settings.xml file?

Tags: linux, smartgit

I need the solution for installing smartgit using non commercial version-6.0.7.
It asking license key to go further steps.
Can you please help me install git on linux

Comment: *asking license key to go further steps* ... okay, so what do you want us to help? which Linux distribution? why smartgit?

Comment: Linux Fedora 20. I installed smartgit-6.0.7 because smartgit-5 expired. During Smartgit-7 installation it asking license key but i want non-commercial its enough for me but the non-commercial version option is in hidden, so i can't choose that option and go further steps. Please guide me to install smartgit in my system. Any other further details you need please?

Comment: off-topic. software installation belongs to http://superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

Windows users just delete settings.xml file which is located under C:\Users\nameXXX\AppData\Roaming\syntevo\SmartGit\6.5

AppData is hidden file. open hidden file click [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zxue/archive/2012/03/08/win8-howto-19-show-hidden-files-folders-and-drives.aspx).